# How to merge multiple Models with different connection using Laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel-5

I have multiple SQL tables in different DB's that i would like to merge to one collection.

Something like 
DB: Germany, table: Addresses
DB: Spain, table: Addresses

this is my AddressController:

```
public function index()
    {
        $collection = collect();
        $mandants = auth()->user()->areas()->distinct('mandnat')->pluck('mandant');
        foreach($mandants as $mandant) {
            $collection = $collection->merge($this->getAddresses($mandant));
        }
        dd($collection);
    }
```

i'm making a empty collection. Than i'm fetching the auth user areas that is responsible for. The pluck method return an array with something like this
['1', '4', '6']. After this i'm looping this array an call the `getAddresses()` method.

the method simplified (my real case have here multiple where clauses) looks like this:

```
 public function getAddresses($mandant)
 {
    return Addresses::on($this->connectionName($mandant), true)
                              ->first();
 }
```

in this method i have `connectionName` method with a `$mandant` parameter. This converts me the number's into db names. That are stored in `config\database.php`

My problem is that the merge method on the collection is not working as i expected.

I'm getting only the last merged result back. I should get 2 results from two  Models with different connection back.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you make sure that your `getAddresses` returns collection?

Or you can use `$collection->PUSH($this->getAddresses($mandant))` method.